# Handling Negative Decimal in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Mine is a very simple code - I'm looking to find out if the difference between a couple of dates gives negative or not. Problem is not in getting the value, but in checking if they're negative or not. Here's my code:

```
if !val! LSS 0 (
         echo value is !val!
         echo value is less than zero - SLA breached!
    ) else (
         echo value is !val!
         echo value is greater than zero - SLA not breached.
    )
```

The values of `!val!` are:

```
-0.9513888888888888888888888888888888888889           
63.06736111111111111111111111111111111111 
-1.09722222222222222222222222222222222222 
-1.19236111111111111111111111111111111111
```

First two results are fine - no issues in detecting they're positive and negative. Next two - batch says that they're greater than one! Here's the result:

```
 value is -.95138889
 value is less than zero - SLA breached

 value is 63.0673611
 value is greater than zero - SLA not breached.

 value is -1.1923611
 value is greater than zero - SLA not breached.

 value is -1.0972222
 value is greater than zero - SLA not breached.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: batch does not work with with floating point numbers

Comment: Ok, I'll have to leverage powershell here, then. Thanks npocmaka!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a different way to approach this -

```
 if "!val:~0,1!"=="-" (
    echo value is !val!
    echo value is less than zero - SLA breached!
    ) else (
    echo value is !val!
    echo value is greater than zero - SLA not breached.
    )
```

Here's the result:

```
 value is 63.0673611
 value is greater than zero - SLA not breached.

 value is -.95138889
 value is less than zero - SLA breached

 value is -1.0972222
 value is less than zero - SLA breached

 value is -1.1923611
 value is less than zero - SLA breached
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: The value `0` or `0.000` or `+0.0` or `-.0` will be handled incorrectly, but `if !val:.=! EQU 0` should handle that...

Comment: My results won't produce a +0.0 and I verified that -.0 works fine as well (sla breached). The logic that I use is OK to consider 0 or 0.000 as positive (sla not breached) :-) Thanks @aschipfl!